# Email for openshift application

Tags: domain-name-system, email-server, openshift-online-2, email

As far as I know,OpenShift (free) don't have email server (That's right?). Can I add a mx record to domain (have Cname record to openshift application) and use another server to send and receive email?

Then what is best email server? Is there any way to directly using gmail?!

Sorry, I'm newbie!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MX means mail exchanger. You should point your domains MX record to a server that actually runs a mail server and is willing to accept mails for you. You can use any of the email hosting services that lets you use your own domain.

Openshift doesn't allow access to SMTP port 25, so you cannot run any mail server on openshift gears.

Asking for best email server is not a proper question, there is nothing that works best in every situation.